# Added multiple CompletableFuture of Different Type in a List of CompletableFeature

Tags: java, completable-future

I  have below completable features.I want to add the  add the respective futures in the list only when the provideTestNumbers /provideTestAuthor is true.  How to  create a generic List> where all these futures can be added.So that unnecessary waiting time is not getting added   for Futures to complete which is not requested.

```
CompletableFuture<List<TestNumber>> dbTestfuture=null;
CompletableFuture<List<TestNumber>> dbAuthorFuture=null;

List<CompletableFuture<List<Object>>> futureList=new ArrayList();


CompletableFuture<List<Test>> dbTestfuture=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()
               ->testDao.findTestDetails("abc");  
futureList.add(dbTestfuture); //Error .Expected Object . Added List<Test>

if(provideTestNumbers){
CompletableFuture<List<TestNumber>> dbTestNumberFuture=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()
               ->testDao.findTestNumbers("abc"); 
futureList.add(dbTestNumberFuture); //Error .Expected Object . Added TestNumber

}

if(provideTestAuthor){
CompletableFuture<List<TestAuthor>> dbAuthorFuture=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()
               ->testDao.findTestNumbers("abc"); 
futureList.add(dbTestNumberFuture); //Error .Expected Object . Added TestAuthor

}

CompletableFuture.allOf(futureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futureList.size])).join()
```

How to  create a generic List> where all these futures can be added.So that unnecessary waiting time is not getting added   for Futures to complete which is not requested.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to collect the list of futures for `join` you can declare the list to accept any type of `CompletableFuture`.

```
List<CompletableFuture<?>> futureList=new ArrayList<>();
...
CompletableFuture.allOf(futureList.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
```